# how to merge results of various queries in datagrid view at expected place in wpf c# application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: Expected view of wpf window]

I am new in .net and c# with WPF.
Attached image is manually created to have idea about expected view. 
Description of image :
ID            : user id is a field needs to pick from table nworksuser.
Employee name : Employee name field needs to pick from table nworksuser.
Leaves-Total and Leaves-Balance : these are total leaves employee have in year and balance leave is balance leaves of employee at current date.
Same formula for Holidays too.

then we need to add scrollable calendar dates starts from 1/1/2016 to 31/12/2016 for this year and needs to change as per year passes. status for every single date is attended or not attended.(cross or right sign as shown in image.)

NOTE : Above the table appearing in image, there will be a combobox, in the drop down list of combo box there will be checkbox for every record and user will be able choose all or some of them and accordingly record will show.

How this is possible? which controls should I use?
 "Thanks in advance".

Comment: you want this type of grid as comboboxItem?

Comment: Not necessary but If I choose some of records from combobox drop down. Table should display only related information.

Comment: and from where this related Item come ?

Comment: I dont have paid version. I have datagrid like         <DataGrid  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="15" Name="Datagrid_AttendanceLog" />